# Call function on lose focus or timeout Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple inputs where the user can change the value.

I have a code that works well with a timeout but I want to fire it whether the timeout has passed or when the user loses the focus, here is my code :

```
const WAIT_INTERVAL = 500;

changeValue(personal, e){
            let self = this;

            e.persist();
            if(this.state.typingTimeout){
                clearTimeout(this.state.typingTimeout);
            }

            this.setState({
                typingTimeout: setTimeout(function(){
                    self.props.updatePersonal(personal, e.target.value);
                }, WAIT_INTERVAL),
            })
}
```

I don't want it to be fire twice and I don't know how to apply this case.

How to apply this code when the focus is lost?

Thanks you!

Comment: Is your code working on **losing of focus**?

Comment: This is not working on losing focus. Only when timeout has passed

Comment: you can use `onblur` event.

Comment: But the code would be fire twice, wouldn't be?

Comment: you could `clearTimeout` `onblur()` or you can have Boolean to handle this.